# How do i remove store view name from URL

Tags: magento-1.9, url, store-view, stores

Can any one point me on how to remove storeview name from my store?

When I go to `www.domain.com`

it works fine but when i try to go to a category or contact page or other products pages, it changes to

```
www.domain.com/storeview/category...

www.domain.com/storeview/products/...
```

and when i click on logo which is suppose to give me the base url, what it does is www.domain.com/storeview

instead of `www.domain.com`

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the relevant setting at `System > Configuration > Web > Add Store Code to URLs`.

Comment: Wow thanks, that was very helpful. just to imagine it was in plain sight.   Thank you Tim. may i ask you for a little more help on fixing something else?

Comment: Sure, what do you need help with?